# How to convert a folder of images into X and Y batches with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Say I have a folder of images such as:

```
PetData
|
Dog - images
|
Cat - images
```

How would I transform it into (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) format? I see this format used extensively with the MNIST dataset which goes like:

```py
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

However i'd like to do this with my own folder of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mnist.load_data()` returns two tuples with the content of the images and the labels in `uint8` arrays. You should get those arrays by loading the images of your folders (you can use modules such as `PIL.Image` in order to load X, your y is just the set labels provided by the folder name).

`PIL.Image` use example:

```py
from PIL import Image
import glob

for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    im = Image.open(infile)
```

To split train/test you can use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your train or test images are in folder **PetData** each class in separate folder as **Dog** and **Cat**. You can use **ImageDataGenerator** to prepare your train/test data as below:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models

model = models.Sequential()
#define your model
#..........
#......


#Using ImageDataGenerator to read images from directories
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_dir = "PetData/"
#PetData/Dog/  : dog images
#PetData/Cat/  : cat images
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory( train_dir, target_size=(150, 150), batch_size=20)

history = model.fit_generator( train_generator, steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=30) #fit the model using train_generator
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import images from a folder in your computer you can import images 1 by 1 from the folder in insert the in a list.

Your folder format is as you have shown:

```
PetData
|
Dog - images
|
Cat - images
```

Assume `path` is a variable storing the address of PetData folder. We will use OpenCV to import images but you can use other libraries as well.

```
data = []
label = []
Files = ['Dog', 'Cat']
label_val = 0

for files in Files:
    cpath = os.path.join(path, files)
    cpath = os.path.join(cpath, 'images')
    for img in os.listdir(cpath):
        image_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(cpath, img), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        data.append(image_array)
        label.append(label_val)
    label_val = 1
```

Convert the list to a numpy array.

```
data = np.asarray(data)
label = np.asarray(label)
```

After importing the images you can use `train_test_split` to split the data for training and testing.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, label, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```