# How to use cross-validation with keras image datasets from directories?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have an image dataset in keras which I loaded separately between train and test directly from the respective function:

```
from tensorflow import keras

tds = keras.preprocessing\
    .image_dataset_from_directory('dataset_folder', seed=123,
                                  validation_split=0.35, subset='training')

vds = keras.preprocessing\
    .image_dataset_from_directory('dataset_folder', seed=123,
                                  validation_split=0.35, subset='validation')
```

Then I go through the usual phases of my neural network:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

num_classes = 5

model = Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0/255,
                                                input_shape=(256, 256, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes)])

model\
    .compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'],
             loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))

hist = model.fit(tds, validation_data=vds, epochs=15)
```

How can I implement a cross-validation using either `KFold` or `StratifiedKFold` within `sklearn.model_selection`? If in order to be able to do that I have to change how the data is loaded, I'll also be glad to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these suggestions for implementing cross validation in Keras:

[Cross Validation in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085182/cross-validation-in-keras)

https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-performance-deep-learning-models-keras/

Loading the data using image_dataset_from_directory will generate a tf.data.dataset object which I am not sure will help in the above implementation. One alternative is to convert the images into Numpy arrays which can then be processed by K-fold. For that you can refer to the following:

[How to convert a folder of images into X and Y batches with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805263/how-to-convert-a-folder-of-images-into-x-and-y-batches-with-keras)

Note: The following statement is mentioned in the machine learning mastery link given above:

> Cross validation is often not used for evaluating deep learning models because of the greater computational expense. For example k-fold cross validation is often used with 5 or 10 folds. As such, 5 or 10 models must be constructed and evaluated, greatly adding to the evaluation time of a model.

Comment: I've read a few of those links, but honestly they didn't help me. I managed to create the folding, but it required a refactoring of the code for loading the data. Anyway, thanks for the help.